# pjsip build problems in centos 7

Tags: build, centos7, pjsip

hi I try to build pjsip in centos 7 and has an error.

I has limited experience in Linux, in my new project i have to use pjsip in Centos 7 I download the pjsip library version 2.9 unpacked and try to compile.

I test this two configuration.

```
$ ./configure
....

checking for cc++... no
checking for cl.exe... no
checking for FCC... no
checking for KCC... no
checking for RCC... no
checking for xlC_r... no
checking for xlC... no
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... no
checking whether g++ accepts -g... no
aconfigure: error: C++ compiler does not work
```

I think this is not correct.

I try this

```
$ ./configure-legacy
 CROSS_COMPILE = 
 LINUX_POLL    = select

The configuration for current host has been written to 'build.mak'.
Customizations can be put in:
  - 'user.mak'
  - 'pjlib/include/pj/config_site.h'

Next, run 'make dep && make clean && make'
```

could be right but the make fails

```
$ make
....
../src/pj/sock_bsd.c:147:35: error: ‘TCP_NODELAY’ undeclared here (not in 
a function)
 const pj_uint16_t PJ_TCP_NODELAY= TCP_NODELAY;
                               ^
make[2]: *** [output/pjlib-x86_64-linux-gcc/sock_bsd.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/mnt/hgfs/sharedfolder/pjproject- 
2.9/pjlib/build'
make[1]: *** [libpj-x86_64-linux-gcc.a] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/mnt/hgfs/sharedfolder/pjproject- 
 2.9/pjlib/build'
make: *** [all] Error
```

I need some help with this problem thank a lot.

Answer (score 1):

C compiler missing.
Is gcc available on your system??

```
sudo yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'
```